# Can't supress Chinese timestamp from terminal

Tags: language-support, chinese

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 in French on my computer, and I set "Taipei" as my timezone.
Chinese isn't even installed on my Ubuntu, but file timestamps are half displayed in Chinese, a `ls -lh` displays :

```
drxr-xr-x 3 username username 4.0K 二 3 2017 filename
```

Notice that on the calendar, names of the days and of the months are also displayed in Chinese.
Changing the timezone to New York or Paris don't change anything to this.

If you have any idea about what is causing it, or how to fix it, you'd make me a happy man.
Thank you much.

Comment: Settings->Region & Language>Formats. Change it there

Comment: No. Doesn't work, already set on francais (france).

Comment: @Motiss: Did you relogin after [having changed it](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html)?

Comment: No.
Surely because I'm stupid.
Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to reboot after changing and applying the language parameters.